# MATLAB: convert array of int8 to int16 with half its size

Tags: matlab, casting

I have an array <610x1 int8> read from a database in MATLAB and want to convert it to <305x1 int16> since the data is originally saved as int16. Using the function "int16" I get an array with <610x1 int16>.

If the data would be in a file, I could use "fread(fid, fileSize,'int16')" but I do not want to save it und read it afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is
        typecast(input,'int16')